# The number of geometrical isomers of complex of type [Ma₃b₂c]

Tags: coordination-compounds, cis-trans-isomerism

> Find out the number of geometrical isomers of the complex $\ce{[Ma_3b_2c]}.$

I applied simple combinations to get the number of isomers as

$$\frac{6!}{3!\,2!} = 60.$$

However, my book states that only three geometrical isomers are possible. I could not see why simple combination is not giving the correct answer.

Comment: You have a permutation, not a combination.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, let's establish that we're all talking about octahedral complexes to eliminate any possible confusion.

Fix $\ce{c}$. You can have either $\ce{b}$ *trans* or $\ce{a}$ *trans*.

If $\ce{b}$ is *trans* to $\ce{c}$, there's only one distinct way to arrange the remaining $\ce{b}$ and three $\ce{a}$'s. So that's one isomer.

If $\ce{a}$ is *trans* to $\ce{c}$, then the remaining two $\ce{a}$'s can be *cis* or *trans* to each other, i.e., all three $\ce{a}$'s can be facial or meridional, respectively. That's two more isomers. That's it.

I think your confusion comes about from symmetry because some of the combinations you calculated can be rotated into others.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem comes from the fact that multiple permutations may be rotated into each other and thus count as only one isomers.

Let's illustrate this with a simpler problem. Suppose you seek the number if isometric tetrahedral complexes having the type $\ce{Ma3b}$. There are four permutations for placing the $b$ ligand, but they may all be rotated into each other and thus count as only one isomer.

**Bookkeeping**

To properly count isomers in your case (octahedral $\ce{Ma3b2c}$) you have to count out the number of permutations each one can be rotated into. You identified 60 permutations, so you will have all your isomers once you account for all 60 of these permutations. You also need to know that a regular octahedron can be left unchanged by 24 different rotations, for a regular tetrahedron it's 12, for a planar square there are 8 (including flipping the square), a triangular bipyramid or triangular prism has 6 and a square pyramid has 4. (These are all the shapes you're likely to see with four-, five- and six-coordinate complexes.)

Start with an isomer that has all three $\ce{a}$ ligands adjacent to each other. There are 24 ways to rotate a regular octahedron that gives you back the same octahedron with the same set of vertex locations, but none of those rotations (except the zero rotation) keeps the same permutations of $\ce{a}$, $\ce{b}$, and $\ce{c}$ ligands. You can keep the $\ce{a}$ ligands in place with a 120° turn around the appropriate axis, but then the $\ce{b}$ and $\ce{c}$ ligands are differently placed. Therefore this isomer rotates into 24 out of the 60 permutations.

No other isomer is possible with the $\ce{a}$ ligands all adjacent, but you may consider the case where two of these ligands are opposite each other. You may then arrange the other ligands so that the $\ce{b}$ ligands are either adjacent or opposite, these representing two clearly different cases. In the former case you again have no rotational symmetry with the ligands different, so rotating the octahedron must again take up 24 permutations.

When you place the $\ce{b}$ ligands opposite each other, however, there is a different outcome. This isomer still has a twofold rotational symmetry even with the different ligands; you get the same permutations back if you rotate 180° around the axis containing the $\ce{c}$ ligand and the opposite $\ce{a}$ ligand. So the number of permutations taken up by this isomer is cut in half by the retained rotational symmetry: 24/2=12. That together with the 24 permutations taken up by each of the other two isomers equals 60, so you have accounted for all the permutations with **three isomers.**

**Look in the mirror**

One final note: Since I considered only rotations I do not address whether two mirror images can be superimposed on each other. If they cannot, that is considered two separate isomers (called enantiomers); here that situation does not arise because all of your isomers still have mirror-reflection symmetry. You will learn about cases where that does not apply when you study optically active or chiral complexes.

Comment: it is not obvious to me how all these isomers have mirror reflection symmetry, is it possible to draw a plane of symmetry for these molecules?

Comment: If two of the three A ligands sre on opposite vertices, you have a mirror through the plane of the other tgree ligands. If the A vertices are mutually adjacent, the mirror passes through the C ligand and the midpoint between the two B's.

Answer (score 3):

There are three possible cases in this combination $\ce{MA3B2C}$.

[image: A is both cis and trans]

1. 3 $\ce{A}$'s are in both cis and trans positions.
   [image: both A and B are trans simultaneously]
2. Both $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ are in trans positions simultaneously.

[image: both A and B are cis simultaneously]

3. Both $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ are in cis positions simultaneously.